# Select with CROSS APPLY runs slow

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, sorting, cross-apply, top

I am trying to optimize the query to run faster.
The query is the following:

```
SELECT grp_fk_obj_id, grp_name
FROM tbl_groups as g1
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 grp_id as gid
                      FROM tbl_groups as g2
                      WHERE g1.grp_fk_obj_id = g2.grp_fk_obj_id
                      ORDER BY g2.date_from DESC, ISNULL(date_to, '4000-01-01') DESC) as a
WHERE g1.grp_id = gid
```

grp_id is a primary key. grp_fk_obj_id is a foreign key to another object. There are indexes on both of these columns (I guess it comes as default).

It takes about half a second to complete but I need it to make work faster. I took a look at the execution plan and it shows that "Top N sort" has a cost of more than 90%. Also, I have noticed that if I remove a where clause inside the cross apply then it runs at least 5x faster, but I need that where clause in one way or another.

Do you see any possibilities to improve the performance of this query?

*EDIT:
table creation DDL:*

```
create table tbl_groups
(
    grp_id        bigint identity
        constraint PK_tbl_groups
            primary key,
    grp_fk_obj_id bigint      not null
        constraint FK_grp_fk_obj_id
            references tbl_other,
    grp_name      varchar(30) not null,
    date_from     date        not null,
    date_to       date
)
go

create index IDX_grp_fk_obj_id
    on tbl_groups (grp_fk_obj_id)
go

create index IDX_grp_name
    on tbl_groups (grp_name)
go
```

Comment: Yes, you may be able to use a CTE and windowing functions instead of CROSS APPLY to avoid cursor-like performance. Add `CREATE TABLE` DDL, and sample data `INSERT` statements to your question to facilitate a working answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need better indexing, and a bit of a rewrite.

Because you’re only using one table, you can use ROW_NUMBER() in a sub-query and then grab the top row from each partition.

```
SELECT grp_fk_obj_id, grp_name, grp_id
FROM (
    SELECT grp_fk_obj_id, grp_name, grp_id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY grp_fk_obj_id ORDER BY date_from DESC, ISNULL(date_to, '4000-01-01') DESC) AS rownum
    FROM tbl_groups
) g
WHERE g.rownum = 1;
```

But also, fix your `ORDER BY` clause, because it forces it to do the Sort. Because you’re ordering on an expression, you can’t index it effectively. If you can force date_to to have a value, order by `date_from desc, date_to desc`, then an index on `(grp_fk_obj_id, date_from, date_to) include (grp_name)` will really help. It would even make your original query run way quicker.

Comment: Thank you, sir. This improved the query speed 7x. Also, I have changed order by to this:
IIF(date_to is null, '4000-01-01', date_to) DESC
and added index that you suggested.

Comment: Any function on date_to will cause the Sort operator to be there. Try running with just `ORDER BY date_from DESC` and see if it’s quicker still. But also check that the results are what you need. If you can force the date_to column to never be null, you can `ORDER BY date_from DESC, date_to DESC` which will be good too and give you the results you want.